# Problem with metaflac

Tags: command-line

I can't seem to get the --with-filename tag to work in metaflac. It enumerates tags into a file just fine with this command:

`metaflac --with-filename --export-tags-to=audio_tags.csv '/media/marcel/Archives2/Albums/Locatelli; Concerti Grossi, Op. 1, Nos. 1-6/Track 21.flac'`

but I get no filename, just the tags:

```
title=2. Allegro
work=Concerto Grosso in D major, Op. 1, No. 5
ALBUM=Locatelli: Concerti Grossi, Op. 1, Nos. 1-6
ALBUMARTIST=Jaroslav Kreček, Capella Istropolitana
ARTIST=Jaroslav Kreček, Capella Istropolitana
BAND=Jaroslav Kreček, Capella Istropolitana
CATALOGUE=730099444521, 8.553445
COMPOSER=Pietro Antonio Locatelli
DISCNUMBER=1
TOTALDISCS=1
TOTALTRACKS=27
DATE=1996
ORGANIZATION=Naxos
TRACKNUMBER=21
```

Any help is much appreciated. Using Xubuntu 22.04

Comment: Indeed there seems to be an issue. I have placed a bug report with a similar case presentation here: https://github.com/xiph/flac/issues/537

Comment: Great, thanks. (Thought it was me.) Meanwhile, I've managed a work-around by writing the filename out first, followed by the tags and a delimiter, then re-parsing.

Comment: You could incorporate the bug report and your work-around into a self accepted answer?

Comment: Initially, I just wanted to load the result into a database table. The work-around involved coding, which I'm perfectly willing to post, but may not be suitable for some readers?

Comment: Sounds like it should be a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I've managed a work around, albeit via a PHP script, since the end goal was to bring the tags into a database served up by a web server. First, list all flac files to a text file:

```
find /media/marcel/Archives2/Albums -type f -name '*flac' > flac_files.txt
```

Using PHP, open the file for read, then get a database handle and prepare a PDO statement to write each filename:

```
$dbh = new PDO(<database_details>, <user>, <pw>, <persistent>);
$qry = "INSERT INTO temp (filename) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($qry);
$flac = fopen('/media/marcel/Archives2/Albums/flac_files.txt', "r");
```

Now parse through each line in *flac_files.txt*, write the filename to the database using the prepared query, get the tag values into an array from a *metaflac* shell and write each in turn to the database:

```
    while (!feof($flac))    {
        $filename = rtrim(fgets($flac));
        $stmt = $dbh->bindParam(1, $filename);
        $stmt->execute();
        $tag_list = explode("\n", shell_exec('metaflac --export-tags-to=- "' . $filename . '"')) //explode on linefeed character;
        $c = count($tag_list);
        for ($i = 0 ; $i < $c ; $i++)   {
            $tag = explode('=', $tag_list[$i]);
            if ($tag[0])    { // no empty tags!
                $rec = "UPDATE albums.temp SET " . $tag[0] . " = '" . str_replace("'", "’", $tag[1]) . "' WHERE filename = '" . $filename . "'"; //no quotes, just real apostrophes
                $data = $dbh->query($rec);
            }
        }
    }
```

Quick & dirty, but works. Of course you will need to set up the *temp* table with the appropriate tags as column names in advance. Alternatively, you could write each filename out to a second file, followed by the tags retrieved from a *metaflac* command, then finish up each one with a delimiter, say "@" on its own line. Also tedious, but also works.